# Destructor class in TObject and NIL Delphi

Tags: delphi, memory, free, destructor

I am wondering why after I invoke `Free` method the object is not `nil`.
What I mean for example next class:

```
type Ta = class(TObject)
public
  i: integer;
  destructor Destroy; override;
end;

destructor Ta.Destroy;
begin
  inherited;
end;

procedure Form1.Button1;
var a: Ta;
begin
  a := Ta.Create;       
  a.Free;

  if a = nil then
    button1.Caption := 'is assigned' 
  else 
    button1.caption := 'is not assigned';
end;
```

My question is why after freeing the object is not `nil` and how will I make `a` to be `nil` after destructor without using `a := nil`?

Comment: Freeing an object does not set it to nil. use FreeAndNil(a)

Comment: And you can not make that from destructor?

Comment: Thank you very much for your promt response!

Comment: If I free an object and use it in the next source line, the compiler should bring me some fresh coffee :)

Comment: @user558126, any references (there can be many) to the object instances are foreign to the destructor. Thus, after you destroy an object all references are becoming invalid, and you are responsive to reset them to nil. Eg: if you and an another `var a1: Ta` and copy pointer `a1 := a` it will become a dangling one after you call `FreeAndNil(a)`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Explanation:**

The variable `a` will only become `nil` when it is **assigned** `nil`. That means there needs to be `a := nil` in code, which is now missing.

Free is *just* a method, working on an instance of the `Ta` class. Free destroys that instance to which `a` pointed. The *value* of `a` is still the same and now points to a memory address where once was an `Ta` instance.

**Solution:**

Use `FreeAndNil(a)` to simultaneously destroy the object to which the variable points to and nillify the variable.

Answer (score 3):

An instance method cannot modify the instance variable on which the method was invoked. That's because a method is passed a **copy** of the instance variable (the implicit Self parameter) rather than being passed a **reference** to the instance variable.