# Destructor class in TObject and NIL Delphi again

Tags: delphi, oop, class, memory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Destructor class in TObject and NIL Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9753850/destructor-class-in-tobject-and-nil-delphi)

I have got another problem for you guys

I have a class Ta

When I press Button1 , it is executing the next code

```
    var a,b:TA;
begin
    a:=Ta.Create;
    b:=a;
    a.i:=30;

    FreeAndNil(a);

    if (a = NIL) then ShowMessage("a is nil");
    if (b=NIL) then ShowMessage("b is nil");

end;
```

Both instances are distroyed bot only one is NIL. How i will write to know if b is empty(destroyed). How sould i change the code so that it should write me

```
a is nil
b is nil
```

So my question is how should i do to know if in the location of pointer B is a destoryed instance

Comment: No it is not. Here it is a different type of problem

Comment: Explanation of close-vote: The rules for the `a` variable in the dupe question apply also to your `b` variable here. Sorry, but this really isn't magic, or hard to understand. Just think about it 2 seconds longer.

Comment: I am asking, how to know if the content from variabile B(location from pointer) is free(is nothing, is not assigned) after another variabile A(with the same pointer) is freeing that object

Comment: @user558126, here you have a good article about pointers [Addressing pointers](http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-pointers.html)

Comment: Have you understood my question?

Comment: @user that link is exactly what you need to understand the issue. A and b are two distinct pointers referring to the same object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can declare `b: Ta absolute a;`
This allows you to direct the compiler to treat `b` variables as existing at the same memory location, effectively overlaying one  on top of another.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var a: Ta;
    b: Ta absolute a;
begin
  a := Ta.Create;
  b := a;
  a.i := 1;
  FreeAndNil(a);
  if (a = NIL) then ShowMessage('a is nil');
  if (b = NIL) then ShowMessage('b is nil');
end;
```

Here is a useful article: [Absolute (for) Beginners](http://www.deltics.co.nz/blog/?p=586).

Comment: That's very interesting, but what about the situation in the question with two distinct variables references pointing at the same object.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, the reference of `b` is unchanged, each has it's own memory location. here is a nice [article](http://www.deltics.co.nz/blog/?p=586) about absolute directive.

Comment: How about b have to saved up a passed object can be from various source and varies type?

Comment: @Kobik I am very familiar with absolute. In fact your description is wrong. There is a single reference with two names bound to that reference. But the interesting question, the one that was asked, is what happens when you have two distinct references. That is two pointers to a common pointee. The absolute directive has no bearing on that.

Comment: @user In what way does this answer the question that you asked?!!

Answer (score 4):

Quoting [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9753962/757830):

> The variable `a` will only become `nil` when it is assigned `nil`. That means there needs to be `a := nil` in code, which is now missing.
>
> Free is *just* a method, working on an instance of the `Ta` class. Free destroys that instance to which `a` pointed. The *value* of `a` is still the same and now points to a memory address where once was an `Ta` instance.
>
> Use `FreeAndNil(a)` to simultaneously destroy the object to which the variable points to and nillify the variable.

These same rules apply to your `b` variable:

`b` Points to an object, you free the object, you do not touch `b`'s value, so `b` still points to a memory address where once was a `Ta` object.

With `FreeAndNil(a)` you destroy the object `a` points to, you nillify `a`. During this, the object `b` pointed to is destroyed, but `b`'s value is still untouched.

**Solution:**

```
FreeAndNil(a);
b := nil;
```

As comparison:

Shoot a nuke at a random city and be surprised that city is still present at your globe. If the globe isn't updated, how would the traveler know his destination doesn't exist?

Comment: So you can not verify if the content from pointer B(that is the same of A) if is nothing there?. I want to free the object from A, and i want to know from B if the object is free

Comment: Yes! It is IMPOSSIBLE to test whether a pointer points to an existing object.

Comment: b:=a;
a.FREE; // it will distroy my object from memory

if IS A DESTROYED then show('yes a');
if IS B DESTROYED then show('yes b');

and it should write both messages, so you can not

Comment: A nor B are destroyed. The object(s) to which they point are!

Comment: Sorry but now i am more confused, really. 

I am asking:
Compiler create my an object in memory after that A,B are pointing to them.

after that we invoke A.Free(it will remove from software memory)

then i want to test using both pointers also A, also B if the content still exists, so:
if is_object_there(A) - not
if is_object_there(b) - not

So you can not make any function such as is_object_there(pointer)

Comment: Indeed, there is no such function possible. You have to hold administration of your variables yourself.